# How can I write this SQL query for date and time?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to make a query that will look like
`` SELECT * from `table` WHERE args ``
I need to have my args the date from 'yesterday' and time 23:00 until date'Today' and time 22:59.

I'm very bad at writing SQL and I will need masters help for this one.
I know how to write basic SQL and I'm not sure how to write.
Date and time are 2 different rows.

Basic SQL stuff.
Expecting all data from date yesterday starting with time 23:00 until date = today and time = 22:59
Logically is simple, I'm just bad at writing SQL logic.
Date has to be always generated based on current date, time will be static.

`` SELECT * from `table` WHERE date= Yesterday And time= 23:00 TO date=today time=22:59 ``

Edit:
Database is MariaDB from Xamp

Comment: Do you really have separate columns for date and time? If so, why? Is there a reason for splitting them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is MySQL (MariaDB) and there are in fact two columns called `date` and `time` this could be written as

```sql
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE
(date = SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1) AND time >= '23:00') OR (date = CURDATE() AND time < '23:00');
```

This is a bit unusual though. Usually you would have as single column of type `datetime` or `timestamp` instead of two columns, and they should not be called `date` or `time` because these are keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE date BETWEEN CONCAT(date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 day),' 23:00') AND CONCAT(curdate(),' 22:59');
```

Please double check your database timezone.